# Is there a way to add a chrome app shortcut to my bookmarks bar in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium

Some Chrome extensions have bookmark icons that are automatically added to the bookmarks bar, but, so far as I can tell apps such as Postman can't be added directly to the shortcut bar.

If I want to launch an "app" (i.e. not one of the extensions which already show up in the toolbar) such as this, I have to open the "Apps" shortcut window, and then find the app (or launch it separately from the app launcher).

I would very much like to have a bookmark to a specific App in the bookmark bar. Is this possible?

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question. I just mean the apps you can download (not extensions)

Comment: That is why I deleted it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible.

The closest implementable thing is an extension with a toolbar icon that launches specifically the app.
Or toolbar popup launchers like [Apps Launcher](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/apps-launcher/ijmgkhchjindcjamnckoiahagecjnkdc) or [AppJump App Launcher and Organizer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/appjump-app-launcher-and/hccbinpobnjcpckmcfngmdpnbnjpmcbd).

Answer (score 2):

Not the direct answer to the question, but this question is about quickly launching signal.

Two other solutions include:

https://github.com/WhisperSystems/Signal-Desktop/pull/1262

1. [Add a shortcut to your Launcher or Desktop](https://support.signal.org/hc/en-us/articles/216839277-Where-is-Signal-Desktop-on-my-computer-)

Have Signal Desktop already open
Right our Double click on your app icon
On Mac: Choose Options > Choose Keep in Dock
On Windows: Select More > Pin to taskbar

[image]

2. [The shortcut Alt + S](https://github.com/WhisperSystems/Signal-Desktop/issues/1134), however this is being [Depreciated:](https://github.com/WhisperSystems/Signal-Desktop/pull/1262)